# windeploy qt doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt5

I have the following CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(Flamingo)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3")


find_package(Qt5Widgets)
find_package(Qt5Sql)
find_package(Qt5Multimedia)
find_package(Qt5MultimediaWidgets)


include_directories(".")

file(GLOB_RECURSE Flamingo_SRC
    "*.h"
    "*.cpp"
    "*.hpp"
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Flamingo_SRC} "res/main.qrc")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} -lpthread)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Widgets)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Sql)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Multimedia)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::MultimediaWidgets)
```

Everything works OK on linux, but on windows there are some troubles. I installed Qt from official site and installed two compilers(msvc and mingw), but used msvc. Program is compiled, but it cannot be runned without qt creator. 
I used windeployqt utility, it generated about 100Mb of files with unnecessary dlls like opengl32sw.dll, but application is still not runnable because it can't find Qt5Sql.dll. 
What's wrong? Is it something about my cmake config?

UPD: with qmake this project works, but I still want to know why this doesn't work with cmake

Comment: Windeployqt is a nice start, but it doesn't always work 100% of the time. On Windows your best bet is to run Dependency Walker after Windeployqt to see what DLLs are missing (if any.)

Comment: Dependency Walker will not help with the platforms files and other plugins. opengl32sw.dll is usually required with mingw.